# Cloudflare SSL Issues with Heroku

Tags: heroku, cloudflare

I have a heroku app running on app.domain.com

I have a different app (strikingly landing page) running on www.domain.com

I turned on cloudflare for my domain.com and want to get SSL working. I've tried the flexible SSL cert.

However, when I request https, I get SSL errors (`curl -I` gives `no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name`).

The SSL cert appears to say "Active" on my Cloudflare console, and I've set up Page Routing for http://*domain.com* to Always use HTTPs

On the DNS page of Cloudflare, I hit the orange icon on the row for www and app to have them "enabled" but then I just get `Invalid URL The requested URL "[no URL]`, is invalid." when hitting the site.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I also have this issue with CloudFlare + Strikingly + Heroku combination!